# How to declare react-icons icon in TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created an array with name and icon. I have trouble with declaring icon.

```
  export const SidebarMenuList: SidebarMenu[] = [
  {
    name: "Discover",
    icon: <AiOutlineHome />,
    id: SidebarCategory.Discover,
  },
]
```

SidebarMenu interface ---

```
export interface SidebarMenu {
  name: string;
  icon: IconType;
  id: SidebarCategory;
}
```

I got error  - JSX.Element type 'AiOutlineHome' does not  have any construct or call signatures.
How to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: Try this syntax: `icon: AiOutlineHome,` (without angle brackets)

Comment: Got another error - Type 'typeof import("/node_modules/react-icons/ai/index")' is missing the following properties from
type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Comment: Oops... can you share the react-icons version you are using and how you import your icon in the first file.

Comment: react-icons version - 4.6.0

Comment: Problem was in import, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you re using React Icons library you will need to import it

```
import { AiOutlineHome } from "react-icons/ai";
```

you can see on the documentation : https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons